# Help with conducting Granger causality test for statistics beginner

Tags: granger-causality

Can someone be kind enough to advise me how to conduct the following hypothesis  test: I have one independent and one dependent variable, both measured on a daily basis on the same day. I would like to test if independent variable can be used as an indicator of dependent variable with some time lag. Seems that Granger causality might be the test to conduct, but I’m not sure how to do it properly, despite reading and investigating for weeks now. I can program the whole thing in Python but I need a hand with the procedure.

Here's the details. I am using the so-called event data from news which are essentially 'who-did-what-to-whome' type of records automatically extracted from the news stories. Now, my main hypothesis is that the rise of events from the 'verbal conflict' category can be used as an indicator of upcoming rise of 'material conflict' events. In other words: I assume that accusations, threats and similar verbal events act as an indicator of upcoming real, material conflict.

So, I have aggregated counts of relevant events from both categories on a weekly basis into two composite time series: Weekly Verbal Count and Weekly Material Count. Every week is included, even if it has 0 events registered. In this context, I'm assuming that the Weekly Verbal Count is an independent variable, while Weekly Conflict events count is a response variable. You can see the time series in the graph below. [image: timeseries graphs]
Also, both time series appear to be stationary, and cointegrated.

Comment: What have you done and what do you need help with? Do you have some example data?

Comment: Since you have been reading and investigating without much luck, try being more specific about your problem and what you have done so far. Otherwise (if the question is as broad as currently posed) we could only recite textbooks for you, and that is probably not what you are after.